# How to repeat the last command in the Lua interactive interpreter?

Tags: lua

How do you repeat the last command in the Lua interactive interpreter?  Pressing the up key results in:

```
^[[A
```

Comment: What platform are you in? How did you compile Lua?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The up arrow works fine for me in Lua 5.1 and 5.2 under Windows and Debian; if it's not working for you then you should be able to add the functionality to any application using [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/#rlwrap).  I just tested it with LuaJIT on Debian, which has no readline support, and it worked perfectly.

If you don't want to use rlwrap, you'll probably need to recompile Lua with `LUA_USE_READLINE` enabled in luaconf.h.

Comment: dead link, is this?  https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap

Comment: seems ubuntu can install via `apt install rlwrap`